# Update d3 data element after chart is drawn

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working off of the [d3 "Calendar View" example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) and would like to display 1 year at a time with some buttons to progress or regress the year being shown. In this example all of the data (years 1990-2010) arrive with the `d3.csv` call and is being rendered in a chart defined by...

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(1990, 2011))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

I would like to be able to update the `data` attribute on the d3 class and update the chart via a clickable event.

For example maybe showing the year 2010 is default like this...

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(2010, 2011))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

and i just want to modify the data element to `d3.range(2009, 2010)` on an event and redraw the chart.

I've tried removing and re-rendering the chart but haven't had success. There must be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above you are only ever calling `enter` which is designed to add **new** elements to the DOM. There's a really good article from the author Mike Bostock called [3 Little Circles](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/) that explains how the enter/exit/update pattern works (note that it was for v3 though).

```
const join = d3
    .select("body")
    .selectAll("svg")
    .data(d3.range(2010, 2011), d => d);
```

First thing to note is that we've provided a `key` function to `.data()`. In this case the key is literally the value `d` which will return `2010` and `2011` for the two data points.

```
join.exit().remove();
```

Get rid of the old calendars!

```
join.enter()
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")")
    .merge(join)
    ... do more stuff
```

The next importing bit you're missing is to update the existing stuff. You do that by taking your `enter` selection and calling `merge(join)`. That gives you all the **new** and **updated** items so you can start changing attributes/styles or do further nested joins on.